# Windows 10 Remote Desktop connection using Azure AD Credentials

Tags: windows-10, azure

My organization is running Windows 10 joined to Azure AD organization (completely cloud hosted, i.e. no on-prem Active Directory).  I login to my PC with a username in the form of "username@organization.com" with no issues and have enabled Remote Desktop connections to this PC.

If I attempt to Remote Desktop from another PC on the LAN or from home, my credentials are always deemed invalid.  If I attempt to login using a local account (via RDP) it works just fine.

Can anyone suggest why Azure AD credentials do not work over RDP or how to enable this feature?

Comment: You can use RDP with Azure Active Directory: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-nodejs-enable-remote-desktop/

Comment: That link has nothing to do with my question / issue.  I was under the impression that this was coming with TH2, but it doesn't look like that was the case.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is possible. Basically you have to ensure no authentication information is sent when connecting, forcing the login screen to appear.

To do this, you must create and edit an .rdp file.

1. Open the Remote Desktop Connection window, enter the computer name or IP
2. Save connection settings (Show options, Save as)
3. Open the saved .rdp file in a text editor, and make sure these rows exist like this:

```
enablecredsspsupport:i:0
authentication level:i:2
```

4. Load this into RDC (Open button)
5. Connect, provide Azure AD credentials, enjoy!

Note: when setting up the computer accepting the connection make sure not to force Network Level Authentication (checkbox on the menu where you allow the remote connections).

Credits where it's due: [morgansimonsenblog.azurewebsites.net](http://morgansimonsenblog.azurewebsites.net/2015/11/06/connecting-to-an-azure-ad-joined-machine-with-remote-desktop/)

Comment: One key omission here - you MUST login with the credentials as follows: AzureAD\<full UPN in Azure AD>

Comment: Awesome; been banging my head against the wall for hours. Thanks for this.

Comment: @Graham I'm not sure, I log in simply with my email (myname@company.com), the same as I would log in to eg. office.com; but thanks, some might need it that way.

Comment: It seems this is still the case for how this has to be done even with the Slow Windows Insider Ring as of June 7, 2017 when connecting from a Production Ring client (Creator's Update). When I first create the .RDP file, the `authentication level:i:2` setting is there but the `enablecredsspsupport` setting needed to be added. With this setting, I can login with my `Name@Email.com` for the username and my password as you would expect. As a data point, my AAD is O365-based, in case that matters.

Comment: This still works in 2019 !

Answer (score 0):

From [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/connect-to-remote-aadj-pc), the following conditions must be met:

- Both PCs (local and remote) must be running Windows 10, version 1607 or later. Remote connections to an Azure AD-joined PC running earlier versions of Windows 10 are not supported.
- Your local PC (where you are connecting from) must be either Azure AD-joined or Hybrid Azure AD-joined if using Windows 10, version 1607 and above, or Azure AD registered if using Windows 10, version 2004 and above. **Remote connections to an Azure AD-joined PC from an unjoined device or a non-Windows 10 device are not supported.**
- The local PC and remote PC must be in the same Azure AD tenant. Azure AD B2B guests are not supported for Remote desktop.

So, for me, I went to `Start` > `Access Work or School` > `Connect`. I then signed in with my Azure AD account (I did NOT join the computer to the domain, just connected it). After doing this, I was able to sign on with my domain email and password.

Comment: The article you linked to has been updated. It now says "There's no requirement for the local device to be joined to a domain or Microsoft Entra ID", so the bold part of your answer is not true anymore.

Comment: @Froggy - I have not looked into it. Feel free to add a note or caveat to my answer. I was of course addressing the original post, so the whole thing may be moot.

Comment: I think the comment will work as a caveat. If you do not fulfill the requirements you mentioned, then I think it is a different approach with different settings, which I have described in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in October 2022, there is a [new method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/client-tools/connect-to-remote-aadj-pc#connect-with-microsoft-entra-authentication) that uses Conditional Access, allows passwordless authentication methods, and enables SSO or at least storing the login token. You basically just go to the Advanced Tab of the RDP client and check "Use a web account to sign in to the remote computer". There are some caveats, however.

You cannot connect to the remote computer using an IP address, but must use the hostname matching exactly the Entra device name. In my case, I used an Azure VM and the name of the Azure VM had more than the 15 characters allowed for Entra devices (?) and therefore the hostname was truncated to 15 characters. So I had to define a DNS entry with the truncated name pointing to the VM's Public IP.

However, that still showed the error with error code CAA20002 with the server message "AADSTS293004: The target-device identifier in the request {targetDeviceId} was not found in the tenant {tenantId}" in the RDP client and the Entra sign-in logs.

Luckily, [Tyler Sherman found out what is missing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1254366/how-to-fix-the-target-identifier-in-the-request-wa): You have to add the domain to the `Domain` registry key (for me on a W11 remote machine, it was not `NV Domain`, contrary to what Tyler says) in the registry key `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters`.