# how can i login to my Azure VM with my AAD credentials?

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, authentication, azure

I'm trying to login to my Azure VM with my AAD credentials (login with Azure AD already enabled while creating the VM), a RBAC as " virtual machine administrator login " is also already assigned to this VM.
im trying to login with RDP and with this form:
username: AzureAD\username@work-domain.com
password: my-password
 But i receive this error message :
 "The Sign-in method you're trying to use isn't allowed. For more info, contact network administrator". can anyone help?

note: i have already tryed with GPO but it didn't help out

Comment: Did you figure this out? Having the same issue. So far all that works is NOT enabling azure ad at build time and manually joining the machine.

Comment: yes it works but under one condition: you have to disable the multi factor authentication for the user you want to sign in, if this not an option for you, you have then to use a smart login methode link windows hello.

Comment: You should post this answer!!! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so that was my solution: it works but under one condition: you have to disable the multi factor authentication for the user you want to sign in, if this not an option for you or you do not want to do this for a reason, you have then to use a smart login methode link windows hello, please see this for more informations :
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows

Answer (score 0):

[My answer to another question](https://superuser.com/a/1819751/875255) applies here to. It also works with MFA.

Summary:

- Check "Use a web account to sign in to the remote computer" in the Advanced tab of MSTC.
- Use the Entra device name for the connection, probably requiring you to add a DNS entry.
- Add your domain to the registry key `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Domain`.